# Form validation using jquery.validate.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My javascript validate function:

```
    $("form[id='form']").validate({
              Name: "required",
              submitHandler: function() {
                 formSubmit();
               }
      });
```

I not just want 'Name' it to be required but also  want to validate  combination words that does not contain special character.

What should I change in above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `c:forEach` tag has nothing to do with DataTables. It's a tag from JSTL that you can still use with FooTable or any JS plugin. You should only need to create the table as shown here:

https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/basic/single-header.html

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable();
});
```

Be aware: you should not be confussing the `p:dataTable` tag, which you can (and should) still use, with the DataTables plugin. They are not related.